# How to remove quotes in output while scraping?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping Dmoz website and I made a lot of functions but I just wanna show you the function in which I am facing problem and that is whenever I print the output I get `quotes` in regional_subcategories b/w different region, and I wanna remove it. I used `strip` in list in `for loop` to remove `\r\n`. But I faced another problem of `quotes`. How to deal with that?

**Here is the image:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
def Regional_category(self, response):
    items = response.meta['items']
    names = {'name1':'Regional_subcategories'
             # 'name2':'Related_Categories',
             # 'name3':'Site title',
             # 'name4':'Site Description'
             }
    finder = {'finder1': '.browse-node::text',
              # 'finder2': '.one-browse-node::text',
              # 'finder3': '.site-title::text',
              # 'finder4': '.site-descr::text',
              }
    for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
        items[name] = list(map(str.strip,response.css(find.strip()).extract()))
        yield items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you properly, these are not just quotes, these are empty elements.
You can try to:

1. check your `css` selector in `finder` and build it in more correct way to avoid empty data;
2. or try to filter them manually. Here is the example how to do it in more clear way:

```
# I omit `find.strip()` since you have hardcoded values there
items[name] = [i.strip() for i in response.css(find).extract() if i.strip()]
```